I get a null check operator error when using the Get.toNamed parameter with the Getx package
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Sizer(
      builder: (context, orientation, deviceType) {
        return GetMaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          initialRoute: Routes.splash,
          onGenerateRoute: Routes.generateRoute,
          getPages: [
            GetPage(
              name: '/splash',
              page: () => const Splash(),
            ),
            GetPage(
              name: '/signin',
              page: () => SignIn(),
            ),
            GetPage(
                name: '/signup',
                page: () => SignUp(),
                transition: Transition.fadeIn,
                transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 800)),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

main.dart
class SignUp extends StatelessWidget {
  SignUp({super.key});

  final SignUpController controller = Get.put(SignUpController());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            CustomForm(
              controller: controller.usernameController,
              icon: const Icon(
                Ionicons.person,
                size: 18,
              ),
              hintText: 'Username',
              type: TextInputType.text,
              obs: false,
              action: TextInputAction.next,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 16,
            ),
            CustomForm(
              controller: controller.emailController,
              hintText: 'Email',
              icon: const Icon(
                Ionicons.mail,
                size: 18,
              ),
              type: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              obs: false,
              action: TextInputAction.next,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 18,
            ),
            CustomForm(
              controller: controller.passwordController,
              hintText: 'Password',
              onTap: () {
                controller.showPassword();
                Get.forceAppUpdate();
              },
              icon: Icon(
                controller.passwordObs.value ? Ionicons.eye_off : Ionicons.eye,
                size: 18,
              ),
              type: TextInputType.text,
              obs: controller.passwordObs.value,
              action: TextInputAction.done,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 8,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Forgot Password',
                  style: forgotPassword,
                )
              ],
            ),
            const Spacer(),
            RichText(
              text: TextSpan(
                text: 'I already have an account. ',
                style: forgotPassword,
                children: [
                  TextSpan(
                      text: 'Sign in.',
                      style: underline,
                      recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                        ..onTap = () {
                          Get.toNamed('/signin');
                        }),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

sign_up.dart
class SignUpController extends GetxController {
  final TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController usernameController = TextEditingController();

  final passwordObs = true.obs;

  void showPassword() {
    passwordObs.value = !passwordObs.value;
  }
}

signup_controller.dart
class SignInController extends GetxController {
  final TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
}

signin_controller.dart
class Routes {
  static const String profile = '/profile';
  static const String homepage= '/homepage';
  static const String programs = '/programs';
  static const String signup = '/signup';
  static const String splash = '/splash';
  static const String signin = '/signin';

  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case signup:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SignUp());
      case profile:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const Profile());
      case homepage:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Homepage());
      case programs:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const Programs());
      case splash:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const Splash());
      case signin:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SignIn());
      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: Text('Error: ${settings.name}'),
            ),
          ),
        );
    }
  }
}

routes.dart
I am trying to navigate to the signin route with the help of TapGestureRecognizer in the signup.dart file. If I try to go with the Get.toNamed statement, it gives me the Null check operator used on a null value error. But if I try to go as Get.to(SignIn()), it can redirect me to the SignIn page without any errors. Nowhere in my code do I use '!, ?' There are no such expressions. I don't understand why I can't go to this page with the Get.toNamed parameter and why it returns null. How can I use the Get.toNamed parameter?

https://pub.dev/documentation/go_router/latest/topics/Named%20routes-topic.html
